# Video.js Vimeo direct MP4 link

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

I've been using the video.js plugin and Vimeo for over a year now, its all worked perfectly by using the direct MP4 link provided from Vimeo Pro account. It's now stopped working in chrome, it looks to be the player isn't working with HTML5. The player still works in firefox, IE and safari as it defaults to the flash player.

Developer tools isn't throwing any errors.

How do I get it to work again in chrome?

Comment: A link to an example would help here

Comment: http://www.webuildrail.com the big play button in the middle

Comment: That's strange. It is working [here](http://jsbin.com/xosore/1/edit?html,output) on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can user latest version of videojs and css file also add data-setup attribute in video tag